# Two columns list data into multiple row with same reference id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
|ID |Pass | Fail | Pass_student_ID |Failed_student_ID|
|:-:|:---:|:----:|:---------------:|:---------------:|
| 1 |  2  |   0  |    [101,102]    |        0        |
| 2 |  1  |   1  |      [102]      |       101       |
| 3 |  0  |   1  |    [101,102]    |        0        |
```

I want an output like this

```
| ID|Student_ID|Status|
|:-:|:--------:|:----:|
| 1 |    101   | Pass |
| 1 |    102   | Pass |
| 2 |    101   | Fail |
| 2 |    102   | Pass |
| 3 |    101   | Fail |
| 3 |    102   | Fail |
```

How do I write in python to get this kind of data frame?

Comment: Your input is ambiguous, please provide a reproducible constructor. Also, what happens in case several students fail within an ID?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove `Pass/Fail` columns, unpivot by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), convert lists to scalars by [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), filter out `0` values and for `Status` filter first `4` values of columns names, last sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
import ast

#if lists are string representation
df['Pass_student_ID'] = df['Pass_student_ID'].apply(ast.literal_eval)


df1 = (df.drop(['Pass','Fail'],axis=1)
        .melt('ID', value_name='Student_ID', var_name='Status')
        .explode('Student_ID')
        .loc[lambda x: x['Student_ID'].ne(0)]
        .assign(Status = lambda x: x['Status'].str[:4])
        .sort_values('ID', ignore_index=True))
print (df1)
   ID Status Student_ID
0   1   Pass        101
1   1   Pass        102
2   2   Pass        102
3   2   Fail        101
4   3   Pass        101
5   3   Pass        102
```

If multiple columns in DataFrame is possible select values by subset instead `drop`:

```
df1 = (df[['ID','Pass_student_ID','Failed_student_ID']]
        .melt('ID', value_name='Student_ID', var_name='Status')
        .explode('Student_ID')
        .loc[lambda x: x['Student_ID'].ne(0)]
        .assign(Status = lambda x: x['Status'].str[:4])
        .sort_values('ID', ignore_index=True))
print (df1)
   ID Status Student_ID
0   1   Pass        101
1   1   Pass        102
2   2   Pass        102
3   2   Fail        101
4   3   Pass        101
5   3   Pass        102
```

Comment: Hi, But my output df comes as list only

|Id|Status|Student_id|
|1|Pass| [101,102]

Comment: @N2M - do you think in `Student_ID` ?

Comment: Yes in Student_ID

Comment: @N2M - is possible lists in `Failed_student_ID` ? Or only in `Pass_student_ID` ?

Comment: Both are showing like that under Student_ID with []

Comment: @N2M - Try add `df['Pass_student_ID'] = df['Pass_student_ID'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my both solutions

Comment: @N2M - Same for `Failed_student_ID` if possible lists there (like `Pass_student_ID`)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), then reshape with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
(df.explode('Pass_student_ID')
 [['ID', 'Pass_student_ID', 'Failed_student_ID']]
 .rename(columns={'Pass_student_ID': 'Pass', 'Failed_student_ID': 'Fail'})
 .melt('ID', value_name='Student_ID', var_name='Status')
 .loc[lambda d: d['Student_ID'].ne(0)]
 .sort_values(by='ID')
)
```

output:

```
   ID Status Student_ID
0   1   Pass        101
1   1   Pass        102
2   2   Pass        102
7   2   Fail        101
3   3   Pass        101
4   3   Pass        102
```